# How long before a weightlifting session should I ingest proteins?

Tags: weightlifting, nutrition, protein

How long before a weightlifting session should I ingest proteins?

I have read different durations as shown below, and I wonder whether the scientific literature has reached any consensus on it.

http://www.myprotein.com/thezone/nutrition/protein-timing-drink-shake-before-after-workout/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170429234411/http://www.myprotein.com/thezone/nutrition/protein-timing-drink-shake-before-after-workout/)):

> There’s very little quality research in existence to provide practical recommendations with regards to timing of ingestion of a pre-workout protein beverage, however use **within a 30-minute window beforehand** should allow some of those amino acids to be floating around in your bloodstream by the time you begin your workout, if the right protein sources are ingested.

https://www.nutritionexpress.com/showarticle.aspx?articleid=787 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170429194443/https://www.nutritionexpress.com/showarticle.aspx?articleid=787)):

> Untrained men participated in a 10-week resistance training program and either supplemented with 40 grams of carbohydrate or 40 grams of protein containing a mixture of whey and casein. Half of the supplements were consumed **one hour before** and then immediately after exercise on workout days. The results were overwhelmingly positive for the combination protein group.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16896166 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170430004818/https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16896166)):

> A solution of whey proteins was consumed either **immediately before exercise** (PRE; n = 8) or immediately following exercise (POST; n = 9).

Related:

- [Window to utilize protein after weightlifting?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/32750/3806)
- [Best timing and amount of protein intake for building mass](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/3167/3806) (the question is quite general and doesn't focus on the timing of pre-workout protein intake.)

Comment: I know this has been asked/answered before. I will see if I can find it.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this answer on another site so, disclaimer: I am copy-pasting my own work:

### How important is nutrient or meal timing?

Under most circumstances and in the grand scheme of things, it's not critical. Of far greater importance is hitting your calorie, macro- and micro-nutrient needs over the course of the day. After that, consistency and commitment should be applied to an appropriate workout plan that suits your performance and/or body goals. If you tend to train in a fasted state, getting your post-workout nutrition in as soon as possible is a good idea, but the first two points (daily diet goals, consistent training) still take precedence.

For a good paper reviewing the literature examining the ideas and research behind nutrient timing and the "post-workout window", check out this [meta-review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3577439/pdf/1550-2783-10-5.pdf).

For a review specific to protein timing and it's effect on strength and muscle building, check out [this review](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3879660/).